# Photos won't upload using laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.6 before, my photos uploaded perfectly and now that I've upgraded to 5.7, now they wont and I'm at a loss. The posts will upload, just not the photos. I have checked any rechecked the relationships and routes gut to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

home.blade.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('makePost') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="body" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Body') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <textarea id="body" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('body') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="body" value="{{ old('body') }}" required autofocus></textarea>

                                    @if ($errors->has('body'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('body') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('image'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Create Post') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

PostsController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $user = Auth::user();

    if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }

    $user->post()->create($input);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Photo.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'file',
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function photo() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

Post.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'body', 'photo_id', 'user_id',
    ];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to `<form>` tag. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('makePost') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //
</form>
```

Source: [HTML  enctype Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

Comment: I added the enctype, can't believe I forgot that but now I get the error:       General error: 1364 Field 'photo_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`body`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asdfasdf, 1, 2018-09-23 18:14:05, 2018-09-23 18:14:05))